# c# encode string to prevent XSS injection (RegEx??)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains valid html tags like `<table>` or `<br/>` and that is displayed in a tooltip including database.  Security team considers this a a critical issue as this could allow xss attacks from a user that would insert an `<script> alert(...)`

Everywhere on the web,  I'm told to use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`.  Problem is that this is also encoding my valid tag.

What I'm looking for and I can't find is a RegEx that would allow me to filter xss injections without stripping my valid html tags.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: You need to use `HtmlEncode` on the _data_ portions of the page _before_ assembling the string for output. Trying to divine which parts of the output are formatting and which came from a database after the fact is not going to go well.

Comment: Is the html in user supplied text? Or are you wrapping user text with html?

Comment: We typically forbid users to enter HTML at all.  If we need to give the user the ability to enter formatting instructions then we'll hook up a MarkDown processor that particular field.

Comment: Is the problem that you have a mix of "safe", i.e. supplied by your organization, and "unsafe", i.e. supplied by outside users, strings with HTML in your database? If so, then your choices are: (1) output raw data from the database and keep user-supplied data HTML encoded in the database, or (B) add a flag to indicate whether the associated data is trustworthy and can be output without encoding. (Or (iii), you know by virtue of some other (meta)data, e.g. which table you are accessing, whether to trust the data.)

Comment: This is exactly my problem.  I have safe and unsafe strings.  Some come from me and some from the database which I have no control on.  I think that I will use HABO solution and htmlencode all the data portion before assembling it!!

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple, Html Encode the entire thing, then use regex to replace all instances of `&lt;table&gt;` with `<table>` etc.  An example regex would be `"&lt;(\/?(table|span|p|br|tr|td|th|thead|tbody|tfoot|b|i)\s*\\?)&gt;"` and replace with "<\1>"

That should get you pretty close.  Of course it won't allow complex tags, like `<table id=...>` etc, but you will have to decide if that's a requirement or not.  Or use a markdown editor instead.

Comment: that is exactly what i tried to do but I decided not to go this way because i have a lot of attributes to my tag :(

Comment: Why do you have a lot of attributes (or any at all) on tags that are user supplied?

Comment: Sounds like you have a process issue.  You should be sanitizing the user supplied portion before merging with whatever you are supplying.  You could also consider not putting HTML into the database and instead putting placeholders that you transform after retrieving them.  This will also allow you to update/change your portion easily if changes need to be made at a later date.  Storage would look like: `Some user supplied data<!-- MyControlType1 -->More user data<!-- MyControlType2 -->`, then replace the comments after pulling from the database.